# passing https requests trough socks server?

Tags: networking, socks

I tried to setup socks server from sockslist website in my firefox network settings.
I then try normal websites to see if it works and indeed, all my trafic is routed trough that socks server.

However, when i try **https** traffic, the browser skips the socks server and connects directly to the destination. Any reasons why it would do that?
After all, https is an application layer, and socks operates at the lower TCP level, so it should work..isnt it?

Comment: This question is more likely to be answered on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @Oleg V. Kozlyuk I'll try there. Thanks